# Sitecore 8 Bucket

Tags: sitecore, buckets

In Sitecore 8 `Sitecore.Buckets.Forms.SelectRenderingDatasourceForm` is same as that of sitecore 7. The Experience Editor functionality of "Add to here" component using the `SelectRenderingDatasource.xml` which uses the `Sitecore.Buckets.Forms.SelectRenderingDatasourceForm` code behind file is working fine. Some of the methods in Sitecore 7 `Sitecore.Buckets.Forms.SelectRenderingDatasourceForm` are missing in Sitecore 8 but the functionality is working correctly. Are this methods present in some other dll in sitecore 8 where these methods are present. I am currently facing an issue while customizing the `SelectRenderingDatasource.xml`. How is the backend compatibility maintained?

Comment: Which methods are missing in Sitecore 8? What do you want to achieve? What is the problem?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : The goal to achieve is that in Page editor mode when Adding a new component through add to here button, the datasource for the item needs to set. Currently while setting the datasource by default the root node i.e. "Data" folder is highlighted but my requirement is to have the immediate parent item to be highlighted. For example while adding a tab item within the Tab container, the Tab container node should be highlighted but by default root node "Data" folder is highlighted.

Comment: i have implemented this in sitecore 7 but in sitecore 8 the same code used for customizing the SelectRenderingDatasource.xml doesn't work. Also there any better way to achieve this functionality?If so how it needs to be implemented?